# How to aggregate document.ready actions?

Tags: javascript

This may be as much a style question as anything, but:  I'm building a site that uses the Bootstrap theme and a bunch of Bootstrap features -- popovers, dialogs, and the like. This means that I often need to run little bits of initialization code when the page loads; I'm doing these by using `drupal_add_js` to add the needed bits of jQuery, wrapped in a `document.ready()` handler.  The usual sort of thing, I think.

This works fine, but they are all being added to the page in their own SCRIPT and `document.ready` blocks.  Thus the page looks like:

```
<script>(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            somejQueryCode();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script>(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            someMorejQueryCode();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script>(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            stillSomeMorejQueryCode();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

as to what it seems like it might be:

```
<script>(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            somejQueryCode();
            someMorejQueryCode();
            stillSomeMorejQueryCode();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

You get the idea.  Like I said, the individual blocks are working, but it seems a little wrong -- you'd surely never write the code by hand like that.  I've explored various arguments to `drupal_add_js`, and have started experimenting with the AdvAgg module, but haven't found anything that works.  Is there a better way to do this?  Comments to the effect of "this isn't a big deal, don't worry about it" will also be accepted...  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with drupal behaviors?

Comment: No -- could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you using a custom subtheme?

Comment: Yes (I'm using a custom subtheme).

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, $(document).ready() is not used. The Drupal API uses Drupal.behaviors.

You didn't mention your version of Drupal. But you can read about the Drupal 7 JavaScript API here: https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Here is Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515

And here is a pretty comprehensive breakdown/tutorial I wrote on using the D7 API: http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/high-performance-javascript-using-drupal-7s-javascript-api

Comment: Hmm.  I'll look at that -- thanks!  (I'm on Drupal 7, btw).

Comment: BTW: This was very helpful; I'm getting the hang of it.  A followup question: If I attach some jQuery via `$element['#attached']['js'][]...`, is it NOT necessary to wrap that jQuery in a $(document).ready (assuming that the page needs to be fully-formed before the jQuery runs)?

Comment: Sorry about my late response. $(document).ready() is never used in Drupal. It's always Drupal.behaviors, which is the Drupal version of the jquery function you are looking for.